# How to get certain acount's balance using Nearlib.js

Tags: nearprotocol

Let's say we initialize near like so and that the user is already logged in:

```
    const near = await window.nearlib.connect(Object.assign({ deps: { keyStore: new window.nearlib.keyStores.BrowserLocalStorageKeyStore() } }, window.nearConfig));
    const walletAccount = new window.nearlib.WalletAccount(near);
```

I want to be able to get an account's NEAR balance using something like:

```
near.getBalanceOf(walletAccount.getAccountId()).then(...)
```

or maybe

```
walletAccount.getBalance().then(...)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`WalletAccount` is just used to login with the wallet. All the relevant API is located in `Account` class. Here is a way to query your own account info:

```
let account = await near.account(walletAccount.getAccountId());
console.log(await account.state());
```

The result will be something like this:

```
{
  "amount":"20999000097842111450",
  "code_hash":"11111111111111111111111111111111",
  "staked":"2000000000",
  "storage_paid_at":324708,
  "storage_usage":551
}
```

Comment: The naming of those classes and some the attributes is a bit confusing :) thanks for the answer!